# Opencart facebook extension unexpected token

Tags: opencart2.x

I am on version :  2.0.1.1 and when i upload the facebook extension on my opencart admin i get the following error:
"
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
"
I hope thats sufficient information

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when a controller returns html to the view via an AJAX call and the call is expecting JSON. In my experience the unexpected token & html that is returned tends to be a server error of some sort.

To test this out, you should disable the extension, inspect element on the page and record the network traffic. Then when you enable the extension, look at the requests that are made:
[image]

Chances are, there'll be a 500 under the "Status" column, if you click the row that has the 500 on it, you'll see details of what was sent to the controller and what was returned:
[image]

You can now look at what the unexpected token actually is by clicking "Response", chances are, it's expecting a JSON response and it's getting something else altogether:
[image]

While this won't solve your issue, it will help you troubleshoot a little more effectively.